# Laravel/Eloquent: How do I refer to a column of the outer select in a Larvael `->whereNotExists` sub-query?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, subquery, exists

**Please read the question until the end; the final part on usage contains important examples which illustrate the restrictions and conditions**

## Problem Description

Assume I have the following simplified table scheme

```
CREATE TABLE albums (
  id SEQUENCE PRIMARY KEY,
  parent_id BIGINT,
  _lft BIGINT NOT NULL,
  _rgt BIGINT NOT NULL
  ...
)
```

Albums can be organized as a tree and use the [nested set approach](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_Sets).

Assume that I have the two integers `p_lft` and `p_rgt` (like parent left and parent right). Eventually the Eloquent Builder is supposed to construct a query which should compile to something like this on the SQL layer:

```
SELECT * FROM albums AS child
WHERE
  p_lft < child._lft AND child._rgt < p_rgt
AND
  NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM albums AS inner
    WHERE
      p_lft < inner._lft AND inner._lft <= child._lft
    AND
      child._rgt <= inner._rgt AND inner._rgt < p_rgt
    AND
      (more conditions here)
  );
```

The actual problem arises that the query is constructed **at two different points in the program**:

a) The outer part of the query (i.e. the part which corresponds to `SELECT * FROM albums AS child` above)
b) The inner sub-query

In particular the inner sub-query should be written as a generic function -- called a filter function -- which can be applied to arbitrary instances of the outer query. The only requirement on the outer query is that it queries for the correct model, i.e. `Album`. In particular, **I cannot control the outer query** and hence I **do not know if any aliasing has already happened**. Hence, I do not know how I can refer from the inner query, i.e. from inside the filter, to the outer query.

## Attempt of Solution

This is how far I came

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;
use Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder as BaseBuilder;

function applyFilter(Builder $builder, int $p_lft, int $p_rgt): void {
  // Ensure that the outer query queries for the right model
  $model = $query->getModel();
  if (!($model instanceof Album )) {
    throw new \InvalidArgumentException();
  }
  // We must wrap everything into an outer query to avoid any undesired
  // effects in case that the original query already contains an
  // "OR"-clause.
  $filter = function (Builder $query) use ($p_lft, $p_rgt) {
    $query
      ->where('_lft', '>', $p_lft)   // _lft corresponds to child._lft in SQL
      ->where('_rgt', '<', $p_rgt)   // _rgt corresponds to child._rgt in SQL
      ->whereNotExists(function (BaseBuilder $subQuery) use ($p_lft, $p_rgt) {
        $subQuery->from('albums')
          ->where('_lft', '>', p_lft)  // here _lft corresponds to inner._lft in SQL
          ->where('_lft', '<=', ????)  // how do I refer to the outer _lft here?
          ->where('_rgt', '>=', ????)  // some question
          ->where('_rgt', '<', p_rgt)  // here _rgt corresponds to inner._rgt in SQL
      });
    };
  
  $builder->where($filter);
}
```

## Examples of Usage

And somewhere at other places in the code the filter may be invoked like this

```
applyFilter(
  Albums::query()
    ->where(some_condition)
    ->orWhere(some_other_condition),
  $left, $right
)->get();
```

or like this

```
Photo::query()
  ->where(some_condition)
  ->whereHas('album', fn(Builder $b) => applyFilter($b, $left, $right))
```

or even like this

```
Album::query()
  ->whereHas('parent', fn(Builder $b) => applyFilter($b, $left, $right))
```

Please note that the last case is particularly tricky. The filter function is used inside a `whereHas` for an association of `Album` with itself. So the filter function is called for a query which has already aliased `album` to something differently.

Answer (score 1):

> My main problem is that I have no control over the outer query and thus I have no idea how I can control the aliasing.

You can use `from()` to alias anything. For example

```php
Album::query()
    ->select('*')              // ->select('*') is completely optional in this query.
    ->from('albums', 'child')
    ->get();
```

compiles to

```sql
SELECT * FROM `albums` as `child`
```

By default, the table alias should be the table itself. (`Album` -> `albums` -> `albums._lft`)

Translating your query line by line isn't complicated either assuming the grouping's already there (no missing `(...)` )

---

```php
Album::query()
    ->select('*')
    ->from('albums', 'child')
    ->where('child._lft', '>', $p_lft)
    ->where('child._rgt', '<', $p_rgt)
    ->whereNotExists(function ($sub) use ($p_lft, $p_rgt) {
        $sub->select('*')
            ->from('albums', 'inner')
            ->where('inner._lft', '>', $p_lft)
            ->whereColumn('inner._lft', '<=', 'child._lft')  // when comparing two columns, whereColumn/orWhereColumn must be used.
            ->whereColumn('child._rgt', '<=', 'inner._rgt')
            ->where('inner._rgt', '<', $p_rgt);
            ->where(/* other conditions here */)
    })
    ->get();
```

---

#### Obtaining the table name inside your function:

```php
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

function applyFilter(Builder $builder, int $p_lft, int $p_rgt): void {
    // get table name or aliased table name.
    $table = Str::after($builder->getQuery()->table, ' as '); 
    // similarly, you can get an array of all joined tables in the outer query
    $joined_tables = array_map(fn($join) => Str::after($join->table, ' as '), $builder->getQuery()->joins)
}
```

Comment: This answer does not take into account that I have *no control* about the outer query as stated in the question. I do not create the outer `Album::query()` myself but get it as a parameter. Also I it might happen that the "outer" query is actually a sub-query itself (cp. my 2nd example how the method may be called). Of course, if I also constructed the outer query, then everything would be easy. But then I would not have asked the question in the first place. So the answer is actually a no-answer.

Comment: I misunderstood. Then it's actually a lot simpler. The  alias should be the name of the outer table./s IF no other aliasing was done.

Comment: You say "the alias should be the name of the outer table, **if no** other aliasing was done". But the latter condition is exactly the problem. I cannot guarantee that. How do I find out the real alias if any has been set? Also keep in mind my examples how the method may be invoked. The album query does not necessarily be the top level query.

Comment: Ok, I think I got it. You can get that data from inside the `applyFilter()` using the `Builder` class. `$table = $builder->getQuery()->table; ` (this will either show `albums` or `albums as something`). Join table names can be obtained similarly. `$builder->getQuery()->joins[0]->table`

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?

```
DB::query()->fromSub($builder, "my_new_table_alias")
     ->whereNotExists(function (BaseBuilder $subQuery) use ($p_lft, $p_rgt) {
        $subQuery->from('albums')
          ->where('_lft', '>', p_lft)  
          // check if this is the field you are looking for
          ->where('_lft', '<=', 'my_new_table_alias._lft')  
          ->where('_rgt', '>=', 'my_new_table_alias._rgt')  
          ->where('_rgt', '<', p_rgt)  
      });
```

This "should work" because if you do a POC like this:

```
DB::query()->fromSub(Album::query(), 'my_album_table_alias')->toSql()
```

In your tinker console, you will se something like this

```
"select * from (select * from `album`) as `my_album_table_alias`"
```

...Hope it works

Comment: This won't work because the `Album::query()` has been "swallowed" by a raw query and you cannot hydrate album models from that. How is the caller of my filter function supposed to call `->get` on the query?

Comment: @user2690527 you can do the same with `Album::query()->fromSub(...)`, and you will get all the model functionalities provided by eloquent, and so it's no more a "raw" query